# How to iterate through each columns and rows and attach to a string and make a key-value pair

Tags: python, json, pandas, for-loop, xlrd

```
how to loop through columns and rows in excel and add a string to columns 
and rows and make a key value pair?

#am getting columns and rows from excel by using xlrd in python?
host = '..................'
opinion = 'do'

columns = {"a1","a2","a3"}
rows = {"b1","b2","b3"}
mynums = 1234,4562,8521,6592

key = "k"
value = "V"
```

## how do i loop colums and rows to get the output like  below format??

```
mine = {"k":"a1","V":"b1"} #post or put only works if it has this format
num = 1111 
mine = {"k":"a2","V":"b2"}
num = 2222
mine = {"k":"a3","V":"b3"}
num = 333

if opinion == 'd0'
    req2 = req.get(host=host)
    if mine.json() in req2
        req3 = req.put(host=host, json='how to loop here')
    else:
        request = req.post(host=host, mynum='how to loop here 'json=#how do i loop here )
```

## How do i loop through through each column and each row and mynums and do the request.put or request.post. How do I make the json in that format in python?please help me out

Comment: You should look into the `csv` module

Comment: @Joe am using xlsx file. how would i add a string and make a key-value pair??

Comment: With the `dialect` option.   `csv.reader(csvfile, dialect='excel')` check out: https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#dialects-and-formatting-parameters

Comment: @rohitrocckz your `columns` and `rows` does't seem to me in correct format because you have wrapped them in dict but there are no `key, value` pairs. Plz correct them so I can forward. Your mentioned `input` and `output` is not clear so please give that in clear format ?